# Does threading.Timer open a function in a separate thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

when I call a function with threading.Timer like below:

```
threading.Timer(LOOP_TIME,self.broadCast).start()
```

does broadCast get run in a separate thread? Or is it just in the same thread?
I'm using threading.Timer so I can have a function called every so much time interval. I do not want the broadCast function to be called outside of the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can look into Python `threading.py` source code:

```
def Timer(*args, **kwargs):
    """Factory function to create a Timer object.

    Timers call a function after a specified number of seconds:

        t = Timer(30.0, f, args=[], kwargs={})
        t.start()
        t.cancel()     # stop the timer's action if it's still waiting

    """
    return _Timer(*args, **kwargs)

class _Timer(Thread):
    """Call a function after a specified number of seconds:

            t = Timer(30.0, f, args=[], kwargs={})
            t.start()
            t.cancel()     # stop the timer's action if it's still waiting

    """

    def __init__(self, interval, function, args=[], kwargs={}):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.interval = interval
        self.function = function
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.finished = Event()
```

[Source code available in Python source code repository](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/threading.py).

If you want timers and your main thread is not doing co-operative multitasking, I suggest you refactor your code so that you can use it from other threads.